# how to avoid blank input by using getline()?

Tags: c++

When I just press enter without input anything, `getline()` function also receive the blank input. How to fix it to not allow blank input(Has character and/or number and/or symbol)?

```
string Keyboard::getInput() const
{
    string input;

    getline(cin, input);

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Call `getline` in a loop until you get valid input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep re-doing the getline as long as the input is blank. For example:

```
string Keyboard::getInput() const
{
    string input;

    do {
      getline(cin, input);    //First, gets a line and stores in input
    } while(input == "")  //Checks if input is empty. If so, loop is repeated. if not, exits from the loop

    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
while(getline(cin, input))
{
   if (input == "")
       continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string Keyboard::getInput() const
{
    string input;
    while (getline(cin, input))
    {
        if (input.empty())
        {
            cout << "Empty line." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Some Stuffs */
        }
    }
}
```